# Facebook sdk for windows phone LoginAsync method throws an Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper exception

Tags: windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I am making Windows Phone 8 application and it uses facebook login to identify users. When they first time log in they see facebook login dialog but next time when user starts application login happens on background. That works very well when phone is connected to internet but if i close network and try start application FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync methdod returns my session normally and application continue it's normal flow. But suddenly i get unhandled exception on my App.cs class.

Here is my stack trace:

```
 $exception {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details. ---> Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> 

System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
       at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
       at Facebook.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
       at Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.<SendAnalytics>b__0(Object o, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
       at Facebook.HttpHelper.OnOpenReadCompleted(OpenReadCompletedEventArgs args)
       at Facebook.HttpHelper.ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object userToken)
       at Facebook.HttpHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<OpenReadAsync>b__0(IAsyncResult ar)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__1b(Object state2)}  System.Exception {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
```

I have tried try catch block many places in my code but i't doesn't stop there. Also when it breaks on app.cs it show that error comes from another thread.

This is how i call facebook login if user is logged before

```
 FacebookSession facebookSession = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync();
```

And it returns immediately and gives current session. But about ten seconds later app crashes. Can anyone give me a hint how i can handle that error correctly or how i can prevent that? I use 0.8 facebook sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: [Facebook Wrap Exception Wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882568/facebook-wrap-exception-wrapper)

This is the same bug already fixed in GitHub repo but not yet available via NuGet. The solution to your problem is to build Facebook.Client from source instead of downloading it with NuGet.